# custom data under unit test result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I want to add custom details to the unit test result under error message. I am using Microsoft visual studio test tools for unit testing.

I tried using `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` but that adds the data under `Result StandardOutput`, but I want the custom data in Result Message.

Any idea how to achieve that

Comment: What framework do you use? What´s your Testcode? What .NET version?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting. .Net Framework 4.6.1. Visual studio 2017. My test code is calling another api using rest sharp which is deployed somewhere. but response status code is coming 0 instead of 200. That is fine. I know the reason. But along with the  message "Expected object to be OK, but found 0." i want to append my correlation Id

Comment: Then override the assertion message by parameter cutsom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All assert methods have overloads with a string parameter used for custom error messages:

```
int result = 0;
int expected = 2;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result, $"Failed result: {result} instead of {expected}");
```

Comment: Thanks Oxald. It really helped. :)